# Mergedynamic cell by value using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, merge, apache-poi

I'm trying to merge by value some cells uning apache POA and I'm getting the following error:

Here is what I'm trying:

```
      int primeiraLinha = 0;
            int ultimaLinha = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); x++) {
                if (sheet.getRow(x).getCell(0).toString().equals(sheet.getRow(x+1).getCell(0).toString())) {
                    CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress  = new CellRangeAddress(x,x+1,0,0);
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);
                }
            }``
```

Here is the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add merged region A16:A17 to sheet because it overlaps with an existing merged region (A15:A16).

Comment: it seems that you can't merge 2 cells already merged. could you try to merge them all in one shot?

Comment: I can do but I don't know why... Can you send me some example, please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to analyze your sheet and identify the first cell and the last one of the area you want to merge. Then you have to merge all those cells in one shot. For example:

```
int firstRow = -1;
int lastRow = -1;

// no need for first and last cells because you are processing only first column

// for each row
for (int x = 0; x < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); x++) {

    // if current row's first cell contains a value equal to the next one
    if (sheet.getRow(x).getCell(0).toString().equals(sheet.getRow(x+1).getCell(0).toString())) {

       // save the first row only on first iteration
       if (firstRow == -1) {
          firstRow = x;
       }

       // always update last row
       lastRow == x+1;
    }
 }

 // at this point, already having identified first and last rows, you can request for a merge
 CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress  = new CellRangeAddress(firstRow, lastRow, 0, 0);
 sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);
```

I can't test it now, but it should work